# Store Image in SD card and send to server

Tags: android, image, libraries

I need a help.  In my android application, I have adding image option.Each time I can choose or take images and send the image to server. here

1. While sending the image ,I set the image to SD card and send it to server.
2. after successfully send to server,I removed the image from SD card.
3. after adding i am showing images from server to list view.
4. Each and every time I am adding images and showing it like this.
5. I can able to edit the images also by setting new images.

My problem is,

1. When editing how to solve cache problems in SD card
2. what library will be useful for this kind of process.
3. how to load the images from server in list view.
4. how to update the particular cell image.
5. how to manage efficient memory for storing images in SD card.

Comment: your question is too broad

Comment: 1. i want to update my profile picture. old image is still there. is it not clear cache? 2. How to clear cache of the bitmap memory?..how to manage memory size of taking pictures?